# Jquery only allow one toggle div to be open at a time

Tags: jquery

I have 3 image icons that trigger a div to be revealed on click. Jquery not being my native language I have hit a stuck. Is there a way to only allow one div to be shown at a time?  Below is my code I have thus far.  I have dug around the internet but haven't come across a situation like mine.  Any help is appreciated.

```
        <div class="row">
            <div id="callout-icons" class="large-12 large-centered columns" data-equalizer="cta">
                <div class="medium-4 small-4 columns overlay-parent container" data-equalizer-watch="cta">
                    <span class="overlay-support">Support</span>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/Support_v2.png" class="image" />
                     <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="text show-support">Make a Gift</div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="medium-4 small-4 columns overlay-parent container" data-equalizer-watch="cta">
                    <span class="overlay-news">News</span>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/news.png" class="image" />
                     <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="text show-news">UW News</div>
                     </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="medium-4 small-4 columns overlay-parent container" data-equalizer-watch="cta">
                    <span class="overlay-inspire">Inspire</span>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/inspire.png" class="image" />
                     <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="text show-inspire">Student Finance Clubs</div>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>  <!-- End hover icons -->
        <div class="row">
            <div id="support-reveal" class="medium-6 columns">
                <p>Help support student development and student exposure to financial services careers, by contributing to the Badgers in Finance Fund.  Invest in other areas of UW by visiting <a href="">supportuw.org</a>.</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="news-reveal" class="medium-6 medium-offset-6 columns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="medium-6 columns">
                        <p>Stay up on all things UW with a general overview of what’s happening throughout.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-6 columns">
                        <ul>
                        <li>Update Magazine</li>
                        <li>On Wisconsin</li>
                        <li>UW Athletics</li>
                        <li>Campus Happenings</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="inspire-reveal" class="medium-6 medium-offset-6 columns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="medium-6 columns">
                        <p>Reach out to the following UW student organizations to offer guidance and recruit future leaders..</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-6 columns">
                        <ul>
                        <li>Graduate Finance Organization</li>
                        <li>Women in Finance and Accounting</li>
                        <li>Finance & Investment Society</li>
                        <li>Capital Management Club</li>
                        <li>Economics Students Association</li>
                        <li>Women in Economics</li>
                        <li>Investment Banking Club</li>
                        <li>Financial Occupations Club for University Students</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End Reveal boxes -->
```

and the script code here:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".show-support").click(function(){
    $("#support-reveal").slideToggle('slow')
  });   
  $(".show-news").click(function(){
    $("#news-reveal").slideToggle('slow')
  });
  $(".show-inspire").click(function(){
    $("#inspire-reveal").slideToggle('slow')
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Usually I'd create a function that passes the div id I want to show...call that function from the onclick of all divs...that of course you'll want to call jt on page load with whatever you want to be the default as the parameter

Comment: The function would hide the other 2

Comment: give them the same class

Comment: Same class shows all at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the reveal divs the same class, and use [data-*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) attribute to store the partial id of the div you want to display, using `$(this)` you get the partial and display that div. for example adding `data-reveal="support"` to the make a gift div, when clicked will show the div with `id="support-reveal"`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".show-support").click(function(){
    $('.reveal').hide()
    $('#' + $(this).data('reveal') + '-reveal').slideToggle('slow');
  });   
  $(".show-news").click(function(){
    $('.reveal').hide()
    $('#' + $(this).data('reveal') + '-reveal').slideToggle('slow');
  });
  $(".show-inspire").click(function(){
    $('.reveal').hide()
    $('#' + $(this).data('reveal') + '-reveal').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation-float.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="row">
            <div id="callout-icons" class="large-12 large-centered columns" data-equalizer="cta">
                <div class="medium-4 small-4 columns overlay-parent container" data-equalizer-watch="cta">
                    <span class="overlay-support">Support</span>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/Support_v2.png" class="image" />
                     <div class="overlay">
                        <div data-reveal="support" class="text show-support">Make a Gift</div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="medium-4 small-4 columns overlay-parent container" data-equalizer-watch="cta">
                    <span class="overlay-news">News</span>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/news.png" class="image" />
                     <div class="overlay">
                        <div data-reveal="news" class="text show-news">UW News</div>
                     </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="medium-4 small-4 columns overlay-parent container" data-equalizer-watch="cta">
                    <span class="overlay-inspire">Inspire</span>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/inspire.png" class="image" />
                     <div class="overlay">
                        <div data-reveal="inspire" class="text show-inspire">Student Finance Clubs</div>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>  <!-- End hover icons -->
        <div class="row">
            <div id="support-reveal" class="medium-6 columns reveal">
                <p>Help support student development and student exposure to financial services careers, by contributing to the Badgers in Finance Fund.  Invest in other areas of UW by visiting <a href="">supportuw.org</a>.</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="news-reveal" class="medium-6 medium-offset-6 columns reveal">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="medium-6 columns">
                        <p>Stay up on all things UW with a general overview of what’s happening throughout.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-6 columns">
                        <ul>
                        <li>Update Magazine</li>
                        <li>On Wisconsin</li>
                        <li>UW Athletics</li>
                        <li>Campus Happenings</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="inspire-reveal" class="medium-6 medium-offset-6 columns reveal">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="medium-6 columns">
                        <p>Reach out to the following UW student organizations to offer guidance and recruit future leaders..</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-6 columns">
                        <ul>
                        <li>Graduate Finance Organization</li>
                        <li>Women in Finance and Accounting</li>
                        <li>Finance & Investment Society</li>
                        <li>Capital Management Club</li>
                        <li>Economics Students Association</li>
                        <li>Women in Economics</li>
                        <li>Investment Banking Club</li>
                        <li>Financial Occupations Club for University Students</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End Reveal boxes -->
```